# Move YouTube videos from Favorites to Watch Later list

Tags: youtube, favorites

How do I move all the videos I have in the Favorites list in YouTube to Watch Later?

At the end of it I want nothing left in the Favorites.

Comment: Questions on Super User are generally related to computer hardware/software in some way. This isn't related to either and is therefore off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to http://www.youtube.com/my_favorites then

- click the check box next to the `Add to` button.
- click the `Add to` button and
- check the check box named `Watch Later`
- click `Add videos` button
- click the check box next to the `Add to` button.
- click `Remove` to remove the videos from your Favorites.

Comment: i'd always loved don't-assume-i-know-how answers =D